# maven tomcat7:deploy fails with access denied

Tags: maven, maven-3, tomcat7

I have a tomcat7. Access to manager app (http://localhost:7777/manager/html) works fine with the credentials defined in tomcat-users.xml.

Now I want to deploy an application with maven3. I configured the tomcat maven plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:7777/manager</url>
        <server>localhost7777</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta-1</version>
    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:7777/manager</url>
        <server>localhost7777</server>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In mavens setting.xml I added the entry for the server:

```xml
<servers>
    <server>
        <id>localhost7777</id>
        <username>manager</username>
        <password>secret</password>
    </server>
</servers>
```

Now application will be build successful. But the goal tomcat7:deploy leads to a access denied error message from the tomcat:

```
...
[INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:7777/workload-monitor  
Uploading: http://localhost:7777/manager/deploy?path=%2Fworkload-monitor&update=true
Uploaded: http://localhost:7777/manager/deploy?path=%2Fworkload-monitor&update=true (2329 KB at 55435.1 KB/sec)

[INFO] <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
[INFO] <html>
[INFO]  <head>
[INFO]   <title>403 Access Denied</title>
[INFO]   <style type="text/css">
[INFO]     <!--
...
```

Could somebody give me a hint?

Comment: Which one is the correct one? tomcat6- or tomcat7- ?

Comment: Both have to be defined in the pom.xml because some goals are only available in the tomcat6 mojo (see http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2/index.html).

Comment: First make it run in your case with only tomcat7 but not both. After that you need to think about a profile for the other goals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not an answer to the question, the problem seems to be due to the fact that `tomcat:deploy` tries to deploy the webapp to `http://localhost:7777/manager/deploy` while it tomcat7, the deploy url is `http://localhost:777/manager/html/deploy`.  There doesn't appear to be a way to specify this as a plugin configuration.

Answer (score 19):

To follow up on this question I actually ran into this issue setting up my ubuntu box recently and my solution, instead of /html was actually to point at /text: Code:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
      <username>admin</username>
      <password>admin</password>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Same with me, thanks Mutmatt, using the /text path worked. For that to work I had to add the manager-script role to my admin user.

Comment: Thank you, saved my sanity late on a friday afternoon!

Answer (score 3):

Solution described in http://mycodenotes.wordpress.com/2011/01/25/mvn-tomcatdeploy-to-tomcat-7/ worked for me.

The mvn plug-in tomcat-maven-plugin works fine with tomcat 5.5, but it gives a 403 error when you try to deploy to a tomcat 7 instance.  Turns out tomcat 7 changed the urls for deploying, so you need to configure the plugin to use this different url.  You can do this with the following plugin configuration:

```xml
<plugin> 
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
   <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
   <configuration> 
      <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url> 
   </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

The magic is in the URL setting that now uses /manager/html, rather than the default url of just /manager.  The original source for this information: http://www.jroller.com/Fabszn/entry/tomcat_7_et_le_plugin

Comment: Also, it is required to perform deploy with a user who has permissions for "/manager/html" path. I've added a role "manager-gui" to that user.

Comment: Update: I downloaded Tomcat7_U40 and deploy was not working as I described in previous comment, while it worked fine on Tomcat7_U30. Then I changed url to "http://localhost:8080/manager/text" and set a user for deploy with roles "manager-gui" and "manager-script". It works in that way!

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with following settings:

MAVEN_HOME/conf/settings.xml:

```
 <server>
     <id>myTomcat</id>
     <username>admin</username>
     <password>admin</password>
 </server>
```

TOMCAT_HOME/conf/tomcat-users.xml:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script" />
```

pom.xml:

```
  <pluginManagement>
     <plugins>
        <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
           <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.1</version>
           <configuration>
              <server>myTomcat</server>
              <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
              <path>/${project.build.finalName}</path>
           </configuration>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Deploy with:

```
mvn clean install tomcat7:redeploy
```